Python import error for google.protobuf.runtime_version and google.protobuf.internal.builder with protobuf 5.28.3
I am using the 5.28.3 version of protobuf
pip show protobuf                                                                                                                                                 
Name: protobuf                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Version: 5.28.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Summary:                      
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: c:\python310\lib\site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by: 

and i see import errors for google.protobuf.internal.builder and google.protobuf.runtime_version
But i see that these files are very much present in the site-packages under ..Lib/site-packages/google/protobuf
How do i resolve this?
I was trying to
from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
from google.protobuf import descriptor_pool as _descriptor_pool
from google.protobuf import runtime_version as _runtime_version
from google.protobuf import symbol_database as _symbol_database
import google.protobuf.internal.builder as _builder

But was hitting import error for runtime_version and builder.

Please add more information to your question describing your Python environment, how you installed protobuf, what you did to discover the import error including specific commands and errors. You're correct in expecting this to work but I'm unable to repro your issue.
